# Data table responsive con informacion desplegable Angular Matarial

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-material, material-design

Buenas me gustaria hacer esto en Unicamente con angular MAterial

http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/# (la responsive)

Que al poner en modo mobile o pantalla mas chica, la informacion de las columnas restantes se muestre en un acordion, tal como lo hace el ngx-datatable o la plantilla de datatables.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no encontre como hacerlo en con angular material, (trabajo en una plantilla predefinida, que solo hace uso de Angular Matarial) gracias por sus sugerencias

Answer (score -2):

QUIZAS TE PUEDA AYUDAR ESTOS CONTENIDOS ASI LO SOLUCIONE YO

PARA INSTALAR LIBRERIA DE TABLA EN ANGULAR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ESTOS SON LOS LINKS:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5r6YmL2QD4

Comment: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

Comment: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/responsive

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/377388)